# C# won't recognize getAttribute

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, captcha, getattribute

I transferred `VB.Net` app to `C#` and when I build it. This error showed up -

> 'mshtml.IHTMLImgElement' does not contain a definition for
>   'getattribute' and no extension method 'getattribute' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'mshtml.IHTMLImgElement' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So how can I replace this `getattribute` call?

This is the code

```
private void captcha()
{
   mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2) WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
   mshtml.IHTMLControlRange imgrange = (mshtml.IHTMLControlRange) (((mshtml.HTMLBody) doc.body).createControlRange());

   foreach (mshtml.IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
   {
      if (img.getattribute("src").ToString().Contains("urltoimg"))
      {
         imgrange.add((mshtml.IHTMLControlElement) img);
         imgrange.execCommand("copy", false, null);
         PictureBox1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image) (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap));
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "GetAttribute".
VB is case-insensitive, so "getattribute" would work in VB, however C# (and virtually every other language) is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `mshtml.IHTMLImgElement` to an `mshtml.IHTMLElement`, which will then give you the `getAttribute()` method

You could replace this line as:

```
if (((mshtml.IHTMLElement)img.getAttribute("src")).ToString().Contains("urltoimg"))
```

Note the casing as 'getAttribute', not 'getattribute'.

Comment: I've done it but nothing happens, there is no more error but also ther is no image in PictureBox

Comment: Try assigning `((mshtml.IHTMLElement)img.getAttribute("src")).ToString()` to a string and then debug it and see if the value is being retrieved properly.